# Достать значение из JSON

Tags: javascript, json

JSON содержит в себе данные в следующем виде:

```
[{
  \"Id\":2,
  \"VariableA\":\"text\",
  \"VariableB\":1,
  \"ArrayA\":[],
  \"ArrayB\":[],
  \"ArrayC\":[]
},
{
  \"Id\":3,
  \"VariableA\":\"text\",
  \"VariableB\":1,
  \"ArrayA\":[],
  \"ArrayB\":[],
  \"ArrayC\":[]
},
{ ... }
```

Как достать при помощи JS значения VariableA,VariableB?

Comment: При чем здесь jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так (в предположении, что нужно получить соответствующие значения всех элементов, из формулировки вопроса это не вполне ясно):

```js
let json = `[{
  \"Id\":2,
  \"VariableA\":\"text2\",
  \"VariableB\":1,
  \"ArrayA\":[],
  \"ArrayB\":[],
  \"ArrayC\":[]
},
{
  \"Id\":3,
  \"VariableA\":\"text3\",
  \"VariableB\":1,
  \"ArrayA\":[],
  \"ArrayB\":[],
  \"ArrayC\":[]
}]`;
let {VariableA, VariableB} = JSON.parse(json).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc.VariableA.push(cur.VariableA);
  acc.VariableB.push(cur.VariableB);
  return acc;
}, {VariableA: [], VariableB: []});

console.log('A values:', VariableA);
console.log('B values:', VariableB);
```